# Format alist into bullet points

Tags: pretty-print, alists

I have this couple of alists:

> `((melpa . 49) (gnu . 14) (nongnu . 1))`
>
> `((nongnu (nongnu . markdown-mode)) (gnu (gnu . adaptive-wrap) (gnu . auctex) (gnu . company) (gnu . consult) (gnu . csv-mode) (gnu . dash) (gnu . diff-hl) (gnu . hydra) (gnu . json-mode) (gnu . queue) (gnu . rainbow-mode) (gnu . spinner) (gnu . transient) (gnu . vertico)) (melpa (melpa . a) (melpa . biblio) (melpa . biblio-core) (melpa . bibtex-actions) (melpa . bibtex-completion) (melpa . cider) (melpa . clojure-mode) (melpa . embark) (melpa . embark-consult) (melpa . envrc) (melpa . epl) (melpa . f) (melpa . flymake-kondor) (melpa . flymake-proselint) (melpa . flymake-quickdef) (melpa . flyspell-correct) (melpa . git-commit) (melpa . git-identity) (melpa . goto-last-change) (melpa . ibuffer-vc) (melpa . inheritenv) (melpa . keychain-environment) (melpa . magit) (melpa . magit-section) (melpa . modus-themes) (melpa . multiple-cursors) (melpa . no-littering) (melpa . olivetti) (melpa . orderless) (melpa . package-lint) (melpa . package-lint-flymake) (melpa . parsebib) (melpa . parseclj) (melpa . parseedn) (melpa . pdf-tools) (melpa . pkg-info) (melpa . restart-emacs) (melpa . s) (melpa . scratch) (melpa . sesman) (melpa . symbol-overlay) (melpa . tablist) (melpa . typo) (melpa . uuidgen) (melpa . web-mode) (melpa . wgrep) (melpa . with-editor) (melpa . xterm-color) (melpa . yaml-mode)))`

What I am looking for is printing them in format like the following:

> - melpa (49): a, biblio, biblio-core ...
> - gnu (14): adaptive-wrap, auctex, company ...
> - nongnu (1): markdown-mode

Is it possible?

Comment: Your question seems to really be about printing (displaying) alists, and has nothing to do with packages. It would be clearer if you removed the example, perhaps replacing it with a much simpler example of an arbitrary alist and how you would like it to be shown.

Comment: I see what you mean, but the example was meant to give the context of the problem I am facing with the actual code I am using. I'll see what I can do.

Comment: That context is irrelevant to the alist question. If you get a good answer to your alist question, it might help you solve your underlying, context-dependent question - or not. If not, then pose another question related to that context (and not to this alist question).

Comment: You're right, I updated my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure what kind of answer you expect, but of course it is possible to get the output as a string. It looks like you already know some elisp (assuming that you posted a self defined function), so I guess you are mainly interested in how to print bullet points. You can just insert a bullet into a string using `M-x insert-char`, for example

```lisp
(print "•")
```

where you use the aforementioned command to insert the bullet point.

Ah... what the heck, it is a nice little exercise, so here is the code to get your requested format:

```lisp
(mapconcat 
 (lambda (archive)
   (concat "•"
           (format "%s (%s)" (car archive) (cdr archive))
           ": "
           (mapconcat
            (lambda (ap-pair)
              (symbol-name (cdr ap-pair)))
            (alist-get (car archive) list2)
            " ")))
 list1
 "\n")
```

where I have named your first and second list `list1` and `list2` respectively

Comment: Thank you, I updated the question with only the two alists I need to format. You're answer got me there.

Comment: Your welcome. You can also remove the strayed `concat`. I had not noticed it was still there. I have removed the 'strayed' concat from the answer